# useEffect not registering variable update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have the following three files:

- Date Component
- Preview Page (to hold the date component)
- useDateController (hook for all things date related)

i have the following in all 3 files:

`useEffect(() => { console.log(bookingSlot); }, [bookingSlot]);`

The above variable - bookingSlot - which is a state stored within the useDateController - only logs from the useEffect from the Date Component and the useDateController, not from the preview page.

Any idea why this is? My only thought is to do with how it is imported into the preview page from the hook.

The bookingSlot variable is *stored* in the useDateController, but the state is modified within the Date Component (separate to the Preview Page)

Even pressing a button to launch "test" in the preview page, an empty object is logged.

Here is the code:

useDateController:

```
export const useDateController = () => {

    const [bookingSlot, setBookingSlot] = useState<any>({}); 

    // Other code...

    return { bookingSlot, setBookingSlot};

}
```

Date Component:

```
  const { bookingSlot, setBookingSlot } = useDateController();

  // Other code...


  const handleCalendarChange = (date: Dayjs) => {   
    setBookingSlot({
      dayNo: dayjs(date).add(1, 'day').day(),
      date: dayjs(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
    });
  };


  const handlePickupTimeChange = (time: string) => {
    setBookingSlot((oldVal: any) => ({
      ...oldVal,
      pickup_time: pickupTimeObj.time,
    }));
  };
```

And the Preview Page:

```
const FilterView = (props) => {
  const { setUserHasSelectedADate } = useStore();

  const { bookingSlot, updateDateRange } = useDateController();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(bookingSlot)
  }, [bookingSlot]);


  const test = () => {
    console.log(bookingSlot, 'triggered')
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Lifting the state to a higher level is going to render most of the controller useless and litter my code, I have tried as much as I can but useEffects still confuse me a bit.

I have tried lifting the states into my context, still doesn't want to run in the preview page

Comment: If you have all the data in `useState` inside a hook - this hook returns `unique` values in each place you use it, so everywhere it is a different data basically. Hook is not a global data storage. I guess you need to take a look at `React Context`. If you add a context and use it in your hook - you will be able to modify data in one place and to see changes (and useEffects) in other.

Comment: You are confused with how custom hooks work. Using `useDateController` in multiple places will not share the same `bookingSlot`. They are still different state for each call to `useDateController`.

Comment: If you want the state to be shared downwards in your component tree you want contexts. If you want a global shared state it's probably easier to use something like zustand or some other state management library.

Comment: Hey should've mentioned sooner in the post (edited now) That I tried to put the state in a context and share it around, but that still hasn't helped. (other states in my context are working fine)

Comment: Nevermind! I sorted it, I just did the context a bit wrong, thanks @super - i had no idea the hooks worked that way, very interesting and useful. Thanks also sergey for the advice.

Comment: That what @super said in the above comment, if you have never used Redux before I suggest you to take a look of [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org) you can watch a YouTube video to set it up. You'll no longer need to care about lifting states up or props drilling.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you should first know the difference between a Hook and a Context.

In a Context, you wrap your components inside the Context’s provider, and eventually all the components and their children have access to that data. In other words, they all share the same scope.

However, that’s not the case with the Hooks. In hooks, each component that is importing and using a hook, has its own scope and doesn’t share it with the others. Thus if you setState in one component, you don’t have access to that state value in another component. Unless you pass it down the children tree as props.

Personal suggestion: If you need to use the hook, and still have access to the same scope of data from both of these components, simply import the hook at a higher level (in this case, a container component which acts as a basic view), and pass the values down to the children as props. This way you won’t need to import and initialize your hook left and right.